# What is font-size, why are these two boxes different heights?

Tags: fonts, html-rendering

Struggling with Glyphicon alignment, apparently I don't understand how font sizing works. [In this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9byLdn1/8/) I have two divs containing some symbols at the same font-size, but they end up being different heights.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.wrapper {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: darkred;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: darkgreen;
}
.text::before {
  content: "60px";
}
.myglyphicon {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
 }
.myglyphicon::before {
  content: "\e046";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="myglyphicon"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems that different font-types can produce different heights for the same font-size, but I still don't understand why `div.right` ignores the oversized span and has the correct (line-)height of 60px, but `div.left` doesn't? Even more so, the span heights differ by 4px, but divs differ by 9px?!

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are the same height. Use inspect element to see what is happening. The problem is in the container and the position of span in the container. Add display block to myglyphicon, then the position of the span of both will be the same.

```
.myglyphicon::before {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e046";
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Okay, perhaps the divs behave differently because the left span is weirdly positioned, but why is it so?

Hardcoding dimensions is not a solution.

Comment: I have edited my answer, no without hardcoding dimensions. By making the span behave like a block the height is set correctly. This is only a fix, I do not know why this happens...

Comment: The pseudo element was 'Glyphicons Halflings' while the containing span was the default font. Different font-types can produce different line-heights at the same font-size which is why the span had height 67px, while the pseudo element has 71px. Then it lined the two different bounding boxes by their base-lines. That's why the positioning seemed weird.

The question how the divs decide their heights still remains.